# Getting exception while running a project in mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having a problem in a project while running it it causes an exception :

**The view at '~/Views/Employee/Index.aspx' must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage, ViewUserControl, or ViewUserControl.**

I think it is caused as this project is in mvc 2.0 and i am having running it using mvc 3.0
but i am not getting it right. Does anyone know about this problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. My project is created in MVC 2 with visual studio 2008 and on opening it in MVC 3 with visual studio 2010 desn't load the project correctly for this the installation of MVC 2 with visual studio 2008 is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the content in your Inherits tag.

A standard view should have a tag similar to this at the top.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage <OBJECT PASSED IN> " %>
```

Comment: But I am giving it in the same way you are telling about.

Comment: My view looks like this                                             <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ModelBinding1.Models.Employee>" %>

Comment: Got the answer.. See on the top.